# Convert xml to xml dynamically by Xslt.?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Here I added my code employee.xml.
The Input is,

```
<EmployeeList>
    <employee>
        <eid>r-001</eid>
        <ename>Dinesh R</ename>
        <age>35</age>
        <deptcode>d1</deptcode>
        <deptname>Research</deptname>
        <salary>20000</salary>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <eid>s-001</eid>
        <ename>Kanmani S</ename>
        <age>35</age>
        <deptcode>d2</deptcode>
        <deptname>Sales</deptname>
        <salary>30000</salary>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <eid>d-001</eid>
        <ename>Kanchana M</ename>
        <age>35</age>
        <deptcode>d3</deptcode>
        <deptname>Delivery</deptname>
        <salary>20000</salary>
    </employee>
</EmployeeList>
```

I want to transform the xml to dynamically by using xslt.
   My excepted output is,

```
<deptname name="Research">
    <employee>
        <eid>r-001</eid>
        <ename>Dinesh R</ename>
        <age>35</age>
        <deptcode>d1</deptcode>
        <deptname>Research</deptname>
        <salary>20000</salary>
    </employee>
</deptname>
<deptname name="Sales">
    <employee>
        <eid>s-001</eid>
        <ename>Kanmani S</ename>
        <age>35</age>
        <deptcode>d2</deptcode>
        <deptname>Sales</deptname>
        <salary>30000</salary>
    </employee>
</deptname>
```

I have tried but I couldn't get my excepted output. I needed output that should added to be dynamically.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the XSLT you have tried? Also, can you explain the logic you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to group employees by department, for example (assuming there could be more than one employee by department)? And also, why does "Kanchana M" not appear in the output? Thank you!

Comment: I have also tried by using Xslt. the process is that retrieve department name dynamically (for example: if i give employee Id as input, It will show output employee details and the employee deptname along with in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="EmployeeList">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="employee" group-by="child::deptname">
        <xsl:element name="deptname">
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Could you please suggest me how to learn XSLT..? Suggest me some good websites that you are referring.

Answer (score -1):

```
According your Question following Xsl2.0 code
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="EmployeeList">
    <xsl:for-each select="employee">
        <xsl:element name="deptname">
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="child::deptname"/></xsl:attribute>
            <employee>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </employee>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the idea. I have tried and its working.

Comment: I tried your code but if i try to add more employees in same department its again opening <deptname name = research> tag. I should have to need that if I add any employee, it should to add inside the tag and again its not open.